# Sequelize adding many-to-many relation with additional data not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following models defined:

```
var Order = sequalize.define(
  "order",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    menuId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      field: "menu_id",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);

Item.belongsToMany(Order, { through: OrderItem });
Order.belongsToMany(Item, { through: OrderItem });
```

and

```
var OrderItem = sequalize.define(
  "order_item",
  {
    orderId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      field: "order_id",
    },
    itemId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      field: "item_id",
    },
    count: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      field: "count",
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
  }
);
```

I am trying to figure out how to add a order with items without creating items but just adding them to the relationship.
I have this initial format for the order:

```
{
    "id": "som-other-id7",
    "items": [{"id": "727f9b52-a88b-4ec3-a68c-98d190564497", "count": 2}, {"id": "7dfd30e7-2d4a-4b16-ae3d-20a330d9b438"}],
    "menuId": "7715af03-968f-40e5-9eb2-98016f3deeca"
}
```

and I try to add it to the db in the following way:

```
Order.create(orderJson)
    .then((order) =>
      orderJson.items.map((item) => order.addItem(item.id, { count: item.count }))
    )
```

However the count is not populated. I tried:

- using `setItem` instead of `addItem`
- instead of passing `item.id` passing `{itemId, orderId}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call addItem like this:

```
order.addItem(item.id, { through: { count: item.count }})
```

See an example in [BelongsToMany section](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)